# Error while running Docker Mailserver via docker-compose up: You need at least one mail account to start Dovecot

Tags: docker, mail-server

I have tried to create an own mailserver with Docker Mailserver but it seems that it won't work.

I have created the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mailserver:
    image: docker.io/mailserver/docker-mailserver:latest
    container_name: mailserver
    hostname: mail-server
    domainname: domain.de
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "587:587"
      - "465:465"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-data/:/var/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-state/:/var/mail-state/
      - ./docker-data/dms/mail-logs/:/var/log/mail/
      - ./docker-data/dms/config/:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
      - ./docker-data/nginx-proxy/certs/:/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
      - SSL_TYPE=letsencrypt
      - PERMIT_DOCKER=network
      - ONE_DIR=1
      - ENABLE_POSTGREY=0
      - ENABLE_CLAMAV=0
      - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=0
      - SPOOF_PROTECTION=0
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN # For Fail2Ban to work
      - SYS_PTRACE
```

And tried to run the container by `docker-compose up` but it gives me an error which I cannot sort out:

[image]

I have of course created a new email account by

`./setup.sh email add user@domain password` and the account exists in `./setup.sh email list` but the error is still there.

Does anybody has an idea what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: check my answer below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75313196/15305903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the guys on [docker-mailserver github](https://github.com/docker-mailserver) I've managed to solve this.

So you should:

> start the mail server, and then, when the message `You need at least one mail account to start Dovecot` is printed, run ./setup.sh email
> add email@domain.com password.
> setup.sh does not know about any running container in your setup
> (because when you executed it, no DMS container was running), or you
> have not provided -p , which would work as well.